# Importing a Webservice response to MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web-services

I am looking too import my web service responses to values1 through values 3. I know that there has to be a prepared statement and other things, but I am not sure how to use that with the information I have below. This is getting information from my web service. Could someone tell me what I have to do to make this correct?

(I tested the bottom half out and it is saying that I am connected to the database.) I am just not sure if I have to re-write the import statements since they are sql and coming from my web service.

Thanks

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO exchangeinformation values (':value1' ':value2' ':value3')";
sql = sql.replace(":value1", datatype()  );
System.out.println(sql);

sql = sql.replace(":value2", datatype()  );
System.out.println(sql);

sql = sql.replace(":value3", datatype()  );
System.out.println(sql);



  }
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
try{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchangeinformation";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "admin";
    Class.forName(driver);

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    return conn;
} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

return null;
}
```